Cloud Build and Run my Goland with MYSQL app not working
I am trying to write a cloud build yaml file to be able to deploy my project on GCE. I have a go project that is running on VM with MySQL connected to it.
I wrote my Dockerfile and docker-compose.yaml file and it's working perfectly. So I decided to move it to cloud run on GCP but getting into the issue that I am unable to connect my go project with mysql.
docker-compose.yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_USER: ${DB_ROOT_USER}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_TCP_PORT: ${DB_PORT}
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql

  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    environment:
      DB_HOST: ${DB_HOST}
      DB_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
      DB_USER: ${DB_ROOT_USER}
      DB_PASSWORD: ${DB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      DB_PORT: ${DB_PORT}

volumes:
  db_data:

cloudbuild.yaml:
steps:
  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker"
    args: [ "build", "-t", "gcr.io/benergy/go-ecommerce", ".", "-f", "Dockerfile" ]

  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker"
    args: [ "push", "gcr.io/benergy/go-ecommerce" ]

  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    entrypoint: 'sh'
    args:
      - '-c'
      - 'gcloud run deploy go-ecommerce --image gcr.io/benergy/go-ecommerce:latest 
          --region us-central1
          --set-env-vars DB_USER=$$DB_USER 
          --set-env-vars DB_PASSWORD=$$DB_PASSWORD
          --set-env-vars DB_ROOT_USER=$$DB_ROOT_USER 
          --set-env-vars DB_ROOT_PASSWORD=$$DB_ROOT_PASSWORD
          --set-env-vars DB_PORT=$$DB_PORT
          --set-env-vars DB_HOST=$$DB_HOST
          --set-env-vars DB_DATABASE=$$DB_DATABASE
          --cpu 1 --memory 1024Mi --port $$DB_PORT --allow-unauthenticated --platform managed
          '
    secretEnv: [
      'DB_USER',
      'DB_PASSWORD',
      'DB_ROOT_USER',
      'DB_ROOT_PASSWORD',
      'DB_PORT',
      'DB_HOST',
      'DB_DATABASE'
    ]
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker-compose'
    args: ['up', '--build', '--no-cache', '--detach']

availableSecrets:
  secretManager:
    - versionName: projects/859473192921/secrets/DB_USER/versions/latest
      env: 'DB_USER'
    - versionName: projects/859473192921/secrets/DB_PASSWORD/versions/latest
      env: 'DB_PASSWORD'
    - versionName: projects/859473192921/secrets/DB_ROOT_USER/versions/latest
      env: 'DB_ROOT_USER'
    - versionName: projects/859473192921/secrets/DB_ROOT_PASSWORD/versions/latest
      env: 'DB_ROOT_PASSWORD'
    - versionName: projects/859473192921/secrets/DB_PORT/versions/latest
      env: 'DB_PORT'
    - versionName: projects/859473192921/secrets/DB_HOST/versions/latest
      env: 'DB_HOST'
    - versionName: projects/859473192921/secrets/DB_DATABASE/versions/latest
      env: 'DB_DATABASE'

Dockerfile:
FROM golang:1.22.2-alpine

WORKDIR /app
COPY go.mod go.sum ./
RUN go mod download
COPY . .
COPY ./entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache make protobuf-dev
RUN go install google.golang.org/protobuf/cmd/protoc-gen-go@latest
RUN protoc --go_out=./ models/proto/cachemodels/*.proto
# Install Compile Daemon for go. We'll use it to watch changes in go files
RUN go install -mod=mod github.com/githubnemo/CompileDaemon
# wait-for-it requires bash, which alpine doesn't ship with by default. Use wait-for instead
ADD https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eficode/wait-for/v2.1.0/wait-for /usr/local/bin/wait-for
RUN chmod +rx /usr/local/bin/wait-for /entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "/entrypoint.sh" ]

entrypoint.sh:
wait-for "${DB_HOST}:${DB_PORT}" -- "$@"

# Watch your .go files and invoke go build if the files changed.
CompileDaemon --build="go build -o ecommerce main.go"  --command=./ecommerce

The nice part is that the env variables are correctly replaced, but the issue I am getting
through logs in go project is:

"error":"dial tcp: lookup mysql on 169.254.169.254:53: no such host", "level":"warn", "logatag":"Could not initialize mysql connection", "msg":"Could not initialize mysql connection", "ts":1.717317656117359E9}

I am not sure if I did something wrong

when I run docker compose up -d on the machine, it is working, but not with gcloud

Can you share the command you are using, Also have a look at this link1 & link2

@SathiAiswarya I am using this command "gcloud builds submit --config cloudbuild_main.yml"

the two links you posted are not relevant they are far away from my case I think...

Make sure DB listens to the correct  port & How do you know the ip, is it hardcoded?Also, In cloud run you need to explicitly specify how your Go application can connect to the MySQL database. share your go.mod & go.sum files

yeah exactly that is my point, so in cloudrun it shouldn't be the service name in the docker-compose, no? it should be the mysql ip? How would I ingest my docker mysql IP in the env variables?

As Per this thread, it is not recommended to use MySql on cloud run. If you really want to use sql database, you check this Connect to Cloud SQL for MySQL from Cloud Run
